# Google App Engine Backend Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I'm having issues getting backends to run in Google App Engine Python.

in my app.yaml, I have added this handler:

```
- url: /backend/.*
  script: backend.app
  login: admin
```

and in backend.app, I have a handler defined for "/".

my backends.yaml looks like this:

```
backends:
- name: dbops
  options: dynamic
```

in my fronted app, I have added a taskqueue to call the backend:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/backend/', target='dbops')
```

when I look at the logs all I see are 404 errors, and the backend does not show up under the backends section, but a new instance is started if I look under instances.  Anyone got any guidance as the docs for backends have not been very helpful.

**Edit**

After some help from Alex below, I've gotten the code running on the backend.  I missed the deploy to backend step.

```
appcfg.py backends ./ update dbops
```

Now I see the backend instance running fine in the admin interface, but the taskqueue keeps returning a 404 error, and I'm sure I'm doing something stupidly wrong.

Do I configure the handlers in my backend.py the same as I do for my frontend.py?  I can access the handlers defined in the frontend.py on the backend instance but not the ones defined in backend.py.

**Edit** 10/17/12

After some digging I discovered that my wild card handler was listed before my backend handler in apps.yaml.  So now the backend handler is sort of working.  I have this process defined as an admin handler, but it still times out.

Any reason why this doesn't work?  It always returns a 405 error and continuously retries.

taskqueue.add(url='/backend/', target='dbops')

Answer (score 4):

`/backend` will never match `/backend/.*` pattern. You should add a slash at the end:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/backend/', target='dbops')
```

Also, on your backend you should probably do the same thing and define your handler on `/backend/`.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I use /backend  or /backend/ I still get 404.  not sure what you mean by defining a handler on the backend, the docs specify that you cannot have handlers declared in both app.yaml and backends.yaml.  but then again, these docs are not the clearest in the world for backends.

Comment: I was referring to your "I have a handler defined for /" part.

Comment: BTW are you sure you did a `appcfg.py backends update` to upload your backend code?

Comment: dang, I was hoping it was that simple, but still no dice.  still getting a 404 when I specify '/backend/' as the handler in the app.

Comment: Wait, if by "backend does not show up under the backends section" you mean that you don't see anything in the App Engine console Backends, that simply means you didn't upload backends/conf.

Comment: Ahh, no I had not done the appcfg.py backends update.  Now I have code up on the server, but I'm still getting 404's.  So, in the backend.py I have declared handlers for "/", "/backend", and "/backend/" and pointed them all that the function, but the 404's persist.